# Query Posts multiple conditions

Tags: posts, wp-query

I have a theme that uses the following code

```
$user_bids = query_posts( array(

        'post_status' => array('publish', 'accept', 'unaccept'),

        'post_type'   => BID,

        'author'      => $current_user->ID,

    )
);
```

I altered the posts so that they contain post meta "duplicated" that is either equal to 1 or 0

So I'm trying to figure out how to make a query that brings up all posts unless:

Post meta "duplicated" is equal to 1.

but I also need an additional condition:

If that post has status of "accept" include that post anyway even if post meta "duplicated" is equal to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use WP_Query as stated in this answer [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts).

```
$user_bids = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
           array(
            'key' => 'duplicated',
            'value' => '0',
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => '='
           ),
           array(
            'key' => 'accept',
            'value' => '1',
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => '='
           )
         )
      );
$query = new WP_Query( $user_bids );
```